# Prove Ux$\cdot$Uy = x$\cdot$y $\forall$ x,y $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ where U is Isometric transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces, isometry

Suppose that *U* is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ that is **isometric**, i.e., $\lVert Ux\rVert$ =$\lVert x\rVert$ for all **x** $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$

a) Prove that U**x**$\cdot$U**y** = **x**$\cdot$**y** $\qquad$  $\forall$**x,y**$\in \mathbb{R}^n$

I have an attempt that basically plays on using  $\lVert U(x+y)\rVert^2$ as my starting point:

Near the end through some manipulation I get: $\lVert x\rVert^2$ + 2($x\cdot$y) + $\lVert y\rVert^2$

I feel like I've gotten somewhere as clearly $\lVert x\rVert^2$ = $\lVert Ux\rVert^2$ by how isometric is defined. Similarly, $\lVert y\rVert^2$ = $\lVert Uy\rVert^2$

But I don't know if this actually lets me show: U**x**$\cdot$U**y** = **x**$\cdot$**y**

And even if it does, I'm not sure how to make the last argument to show that.

Also, sorry for leaving out some of the intermediate details. I'm still very new to using this MathJax thing (I need to get around to learning Latex!) and it took very long to type that little bit out. Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're right to look at $||U(x+y)||^2$, but I suggest trying to use the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)
$$ x\cdot y=\frac{1}{4}\Big(||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2\Big)$$

Comment: I personally have no problems using anything that leads me in the right direction. Unfortunately I'm basically doing problems out of the books just to study. And my professor is very big on not using things that "haven't explicitly been addressed in the book or lecture yet"

I should point out what has been mentioned in this chapter so far: definition of norm/dot product, Schwarz inequality, triangle inequality, some brief info on orthonormal sets

Sorry. I know that's limited info to work with.

Comment: Well I doubt your professor would object if you proved the polarization identity before using it. You can prove it by expanding out the right-hand side.

Comment: Okay! I will give it a shot and post back what I get

Comment: I expanded it out and proved the identity, which was pretty straightforward.

Are you saying I should start with that from the very beginning instead of just $\lVert U(x+y)\rVert$?

Comment: The idea is to apply the polarization identity twice, once to $x\cdot y$ and once to $(Ux)\cdot (Uy)$. Since $U$ is an isometry, the right-hand sides will be the same for both, hence $x\cdot y=(Ux)\cdot (Uy)$.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically there. Expanding that in two different ways will give you what you want:
\begin{align*}
\|U(x + y)\|^2 &= \|x + y\|^2 &\text{$U$ preserves the length of $x + y$}\\
\|Ux + Uy\|^2 &= \|x + y\|^2 \\
\|Ux\|^2 + 2(Ux \cdot Uy) + \|Uy\|^2 &= \|x\|^2 + 2(x \cdot y) + \|y\|^2 \\
2(Ux \cdot Uy) &=  2(x \cdot y) &\text{$U$ preserves the length of $x$ and $y$}\\
Ux \cdot Uy &=  x \cdot y
\end{align*}

Comment: I can definitely see it better now in regards to how I can cancel terms out and get the required result. I have one question though. Why the need for using "two different ways"? It seems that even if line 2 was not there, the result would hold.

Comment: By "two different ways" I meant to expand it the way I did in the LHS (keeping the $U$'s everywhere and expanding from there), then do it again as I did in the RHS (dropping the $U$'s first, then expanding from there).

Comment: Completely clear now! Thanks.